# How to reliably measure performance of a C++ application on laptops

Tags: c++, performance, profiling, cpu-usage

I have to optimize a C++ application and because of COVID-19 pandemic I'm forced to work from home on a MacBook Pro. When measuring performance the results vary even by 3x, depending on the CPU temperature. For example a function that usually takes between `23500000ns` and `24500000ns` ran in less than `13500000ns` after lunch break and the same function takes more than `37500000ns` after recompiling a big chunk of code.

My questions is - how to reliably measure performance on laptops considering the huge CPU performance variance due to temperature?

Comment: My advice for benchmarking is to run the thing a 10's-100's of thousands of times and take an average.

Comment: This seems to indicate to me that your CPU is throttling due to thermal limits. I suggest you try to improve airflow and environment temperature. You might also want to limit the CPU performance (i.e. disable turbo boost etc.), so that the temperature never rises above throttling limit.

Comment: tools like callgrind will count the number of instructions, and provides a much more reliable performance metric. 
In general (but not always) more instructions results in a longer runtime